# RETLW 0 and RETURN command on PIC10F222 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplabx

When I am building a code in MPLAB X IDE v5.15 I get an Warning "Substituting RETLW 0 for RETURN pseudo-op". As I have researched the PIC10 series don't have return command so it changes to RETLW 0. But my question is how the code will change with the RETLW 0 command or it is the same as RETURN command?

Code:

```
    list    p=10F222     ; list directive to define processor
#include    p10F222.inc  ; processor specific variable definitions

    __CONFIG _MCLRE_ON&_CP_OFF&_WDT_OFF&_MCPU_OFF&_IOFSCS_4MHZ


;*****  VARIABLE DEFINITIONS
TEMP_VAR        UDATA
temp1   RES     1       ;DELAY REGISTER1
temp2   RES     1       ;DELAY REGISTER2
temp3   RES     1       ;DELAY REGISTER3
temp4   RES     1       ;DELAY REGISTER4
temp5   RES     1       ;TIMING REGISTER
temp6   RES     1       ;TINING REGISTER



;**********************************************************************
RESET_VECTOR    CODE 0xFF ; processor reset vector

; Internal RC calibration value is placed at location 0xFF by Microchip
; as a movlw k, where the k is a literal value.

MAIN    CODE 0x000
    movwf   OSCCAL      ; update register with factory cal value


INITIALIZE:
    MOVLW   B'0010'
    TRIS    GPIO        ; INITIALIZE
    CLRF    ADCON0      ; ADC DISABLE
    CLRF    GPIO
    MOVLW   B'00001000'
    OPTION              ; ENABLE GPIO2 AS A DIGITAL PORT
    CLRF    GPIO



START:

SCAN1:
    BTFSS   GPIO,1
    GOTO    SCAN1
ENSURE:
    BTFSC   GPIO,1
    GOTO    ENSURE
    CALL    LOOP1
COUNTDOWN:
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp5
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp6
COUNTDOWN2:
    BTFSC   GPIO,1
    GOTO    RELAYACTIVATE
    DECFSZ  temp5
    GOTO    COUNTDOWN2
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp5
    DECFSZ  temp6
    GOTO    COUNTDOWN2
    GOTO    SCAN1

RELAYACTIVATE:
    BSF     GPIO,0
    CALL    LOOP1
    CALL    LOOP1
    CALL    LOOP1
SCAN2:
    BTFSS   GPIO,1
    GOTO    SCAN2
ENSURE2:
    BTFSC   GPIO,1
    GOTO    ENSURE2
    CALL    LOOP1
COUNTDOWN3:
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp5
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp6
COUNTDOWN4:
    BTFSC   GPIO,1
    GOTO    RELAYDEACTIVATE
    DECFSZ  temp5
    GOTO    COUNTDOWN4
    MOVLW   0xFF
    MOVWF   temp5
    DECFSZ  temp6
    GOTO    COUNTDOWN4
    GOTO    SCAN2

RELAYDEACTIVATE:
    BCF     GPIO,0
    RESET

LOOP1:
    MOVLW   0x00
    MOVWF   temp1
    MOVLW   0xF0
    MOVWF   temp2

LOOP2:
    DECFSZ  temp1
    GOTO    LOOP2
    DECFSZ  temp2
    GOTO    LOOP2
    return              ;Warning:"Substituting RETLW 0 for RETURN pseudo-op"


    END
```

Comment: The only difference is that 'RETLW x' returns with the value x in the W register.

Comment: In the context of the posted code a return with the WREG set to zero does not change how this code works.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should really add comments to your assembler code. It is not clear what sections are subroutines and what sections are loops. There are also a lot of jumps with similar names which makes tracking what is going on quite difficult. It might be clear to you right now, but in a few weeks time when you have to edit it, you'll thank yourself for adding comments.

To answer your question, the retlw 0 will just put zero into the w register during the return. Whether this has any effect on the rest of your program depends on what the calling code expects in the w register. It is common for calling code to expect the w register will be modified by a subroutine, in which case you should save the contents before you issue the call if it contains something important. But this is just a convention. As you are working in assembler you can decide to save the context inside the functions instead if you prefer this (it also means you can make functions re-entrant, though on a PIC10 that is rather pointless as the return address stack is so small).

So you really just need to step through your code and see if anything following the subroutine call expects something in the w register. From briefling looking at the code, it does not look like this is the case, in which case there is no effect from the substitution.